# Same origin policy, google chrome, canvas and file:// scheme

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, cross-domain

When trying to read image data from a canvas which was painted an image upon beforehand, Google Chrome raises a cross origin exception (complaining about the canvas being "tainted").  The directory structure is as follows.

```
/html/base/path
|-- index.html         contains the canvas element, references the script.js
|-- script.js          loads imgs/images.jpg, paints and queries the canvas
`-- imgs/image.jpg
```

The error occurs only when the page was loaded by the file:// scheme.

I wonder whether this is a Chrome bug.  If not, which rules do apply?  Are there any workarounds?

Unfortunately, off-line viewing is the ultimate use case, so

- the file:// scheme is indispensable
- there is no control over browser settings at the target system.

Comment: MDN on that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same-origin_policy_for_file:_URIs

Comment: Thanks @m90. Strangely enough, the rule stated on MDN explicitly allows the above procedure: _a file can read another file only if the parent directory of the originating file is an ancestor directory of the target file_

Comment: Also heavily related: stackoverflow.com/questions/3481977/is-there-a-way-to-bypass-javascript-jquerys-same-origin-policy-for-local-acce

Comment: @m90 No ajax, not getjson no external url.  The relationship seems not so strong to me, but thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Files loaded with `file://` are always considered as coming from different domains, this is a feature you can't bypass.

From [the HTML5 spec's definition of Origin](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/origin-0.html#origin-0) :

> If a Document was obtained in some other manner (e.g. a data: URL
>   typed in by the user, a Document created using the createDocument()
>   API, etc) The origin is a globally unique identifier assigned when the
>   Document is created.

You can display but you can't analyze or change data read from another file if the loading protocol is `file:`.

---

What **I** would probably do in your situation (if I understand it correctly from your comments) : I would write a tiny program, that could be released in the external storage media, which would both start an http server and launch a web browser. **I** would do it in Go (simple to make an http server in two or three lines, native compilation for linux, Mac and Windows, enabling you to provide all needed executables) but other languages can be used too.

Comment: Why is it like that? Is it a bug?  If not: which rules do apply?

Comment: It's a feature. But what do you mean by "off-line" viewing" ? If it's about files downloaded from the same domain, you may have other solutions related to HTML5 cache. But if you want to access user files, you can't.

Comment: Off-line viewing from physical storage media (such as pen drives, CDs, etc.)

Comment: So you're probably out of luck. Other solutions (applets, maybe) would also involve some control of the browser.

Comment: I once had to get a website on a thumb drive load a swf file via swfobject (hello same-origin-policy). I ended up starting XAMPP from the autorun file when the drive was mounted. Pretty ugly, but it was the only solution that I could find.

Comment: @dystroy Thanks for the w3c link.  Doesn't sound that bad, so far.  If there is a way to make the image data `CORS-same-origin` (whatever that means) the image's origin will be the document.  Does that mean I can read its data?

Comment: The only way I know to make specify CORS authorizations is to use HTTP headers. But maybe there is another solution.

Comment: Thanks so far.  I will try to get my head around that tome.

Comment: This answer’s correct but it should be noted that the current requirements for determining the origin of a `file:`-protocol URL are in the URL standard at https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#origin: *“Unfortunate as it is, this is left as an exercise to the reader. When in doubt, return a new opaque origin.”* — in other words, it’s implementation-dependent (because the “reader” who the spec is addressing is browser implementors) — but in practice most browsers now treat each `file:` URL as being from a new unique origin that doesn’t match the origin of any other `file:` URL.

Comment: See also https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/0w5mxLMkrNM

Comment: It should also be noted that the spec which has been published at http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/ spec is now obsolete. In fact that URL now just redirects to the WHATWG HTML standard (because I changed it to a redirect a couple months ago). Actually all HTML specs published in the http://www.w3.org/TR/ tree are are now obsolete, as are in general almost specs published in the https://www.w3.org/TR tree. So when citing specs for current browser requirements, either the WHATWG specs should be used, or else specs with `https://w3c.github.io/` URLs (up-to-date/actively-maintained “editor’s drafts”) .

Answer (score 3):

Give them instructions for them to start up chrome with the flag [`--allow-file-access-from-files`](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/).

Other than that, they would need to run a local server instance to avoid the errors.

Comment: From OP : "there is no control over browser settings at the target system" (but maybe OP will have to change his requirements).

Comment: @dystroy :-) unfortunately not my own requirement

Answer (score 1):

It's a new Chromium security policy in practice.
You can't do anything except disabling this policy as stated above by epascarello.
Star this [bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47416), they were kind of wishing to loosen this rule.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/chrome-disable-same-origin-policy) answer also.