# Access iframe elements via jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

OK, what I need to do is rather straightforward :

- I've got a webpage running inside an iFrame (in the very same folder, locally - it won't ever run from a server, that's all there is to it)
- I want to access its' elements via javascript from the initial page.
- When trying something like `$('iframe').contents()`, via the Chrome javascript console, I'm getting a warning about same-origin, etc.

Any ideas? It should be really easy...

---

P.S. I'm not interested in workarounds that don't include an `iframe` - it *has* to be an `iframe`...

Comment: @Vegard Well, have you tried it and got it working?

Comment: Using Javascript to access `iframe`s (or any other resource) when using the `file:///` protocol is fraught with difficulty. This is for good security reasons. The simplest solution is to run a local web server.

Comment: Each file is considered each own domain. It will not work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12587731/same-origin-policy-google-chrome-canvas-and-file-scheme

Comment: @MartinHansen and @lonesomeday: Only if the Op is using the `file:` protocol. If `http` is being used then there should be no problems.

Answer (score 2):

(1)

It is because the website you are loading in your iframe is in a different domain than the one hosting the iframe itself.

See this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Thusly, the same origin policy will disallow Javascript to access/manipulate the page inside the iframe.

(2)

There is also a concept of sandboxing with HTML5, this attribute enables extra restrictions on the content that can appear in the inline frame. The tokens are: allow-same-origin, allow-scripts etc.

More Info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Please check if your iframe is sandboxed?

(3)

Then, there is the `X-Frame-Options` HTTP response header, which can be used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in an iframe. Sites can use this to avoid clickjacking attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded into other sites. It looks like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-FRAME-Options" content="SAMEORIGIN">
```

The tokens here can be: deny, sameorigin or allow-from.

More Info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

And: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7034

Please check if your page has got such header?

(Lastly):

If all of the above don't apply to your scenario, then things should just work. Please post more information like the markup and your javascript.

Comment: Well, I don't think you've read my initial question. All I have is let's say 2 files : `index.html` and `index2.html` residing in the very same (local) folder. `index2.html` is running inside the iframe. So, what different domain?

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon: Ok, I misread it, I thought your site was local.

Comment: However, the mystery still remains : why does chrome complain about attempting the cross-domain access?

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon: I just re-checked it to be sure. It just works on my comp, as it should!

Comment: What OS/Browser combination?

Comment: Win 7 / Chrome 31. I suspect it has to do something with sandboxing. Do you have any `X-Frame-Options` header on your index2.html ?