# Froala editor not working (icons)

Tags: editor, froala

I'm using Froala editor (the free version) and I have the problem that I can't see any icons on the formating buttons.

[image: issue with froala editor]

Is there any way to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not including Font Awesome correctly or if you have simply opened a HTML file using the file protocol the icons don't appear in Firefox (see Fonts Not Showing https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/browsers).

It is best to include Font Awesome like on https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor/blob/master/examples/basic.html#L6 in order to avoid all the issues above.

Comment: Alternate workaround and more detailed explanation found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12587751/552036