# Froala Font Awesome Toolbar Icons Shown As Squares

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, icons, font-awesome, froala

Every now and then I dont even know where to start debugging anymore because i've tried so many things that i'm not sure what worked and what never even worked in the first place.

[image: Screenshot of my toolbar]

**The problem**: When i load a Froala text editor in my application, the editor loads fine, the content submitted through the editor even saves. But the toolbar icons (Font Awesome icons) all display as squares.

**What I've tried**:

- The froala documentation says i should write all those "require"s in the `application.css` file so i tried changing my `application.css.scss` to `application.css` and it WORKS. But i have other sass files i need to import into my application file which is why i have it as `application.css.scss`
- I installed Froala onto the project using the Froala Gem. The editor is initializing which means the require in `require froala_editor.min.css` is working. Shouldnt this mean my `require font-awesome` should be working and my icons in the toolbar should be displaying correctly?
- I've also tried adding the Font Awesome cdn directly into the application layout but that didnt seem to change anything.
- I've tried resetting the cache and using different browsers as well.

It's a very similar problem as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28839200/froala-editor-not-working-icons) but i think im doing everything i should be doing to load the font-awesome icons so i'm not sure where i'm going wrong!

Thank you for the help in advance and let me know if I can provide any additional information!

**update: i am using froala v2 from this link, following these directions: https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/framework-plugins/rails**

**application.css.scss**:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require froala_editor.min.css
 *= require froala_style.min.css
 *= require font-awesome
 *= require plugins/char_counter.min.css
 *= require plugins/code_view.min.css
 *= require plugins/colors.min.css
 *= require plugins/emoticons.min.css
 *= require plugins/file.min.css
 *= require plugins/fullscreen.min.css
 *= require plugins/image_manager.min.css
 *= require plugins/image.min.css
 *= require plugins/line_breaker.min.css
 *= require plugins/quick_insert.min.css
 *= require plugins/table.min.css
 *= require plugins/video.min.css
 */
```

Comment: have a look at this https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/v1.2/docs/examples/custom-buttons , this might help u

Comment: hi Rahul! thank you for your interest. i just made an update saying that i am using froala v2. are those documentation still applicable to v2? even if it were applicable, it seems like i would have to specify the font awesome icons manually for every button on the toolbar which in my case is quite a few. plus, im not even sure if this would still work because the fonts might not be loading in the first place :(

Comment: Are you using a cdn? are you using the https protocol? are all assets you are requesting via cdn requesting https assets?

Comment: Hi Seemly, Yes, ive tried using with and without a cdn. Would i have to do something different to enable/disable the https protocol to make it work? And im not sure what it means to request via cdn requesting http assets. Sorry, still a new coder! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I traced the error back to css that i wrote to set the font-family of the `<body>` to a customized font-family. When i removed it, the squares started displaying as normal! I'm assuming this happens because the font-awesome icons dont know how to display the icons in any other font-family than the one it's created for?

If someone can give me a clear explanation that would be awesome but give this troubleshooting a try if you're experiencing any similar issues!

Comment: Font Awesome is a font of itself, so when you override it for your `<body>` tag, it tries to render te icons using a font that doesn't contain those icons.